# Windows server not displaying image and css after web.config change

Tags: css, image, server, web-config

I transferred a website from a linux host to windows server. When I changed http access rules in the web.config; images and css are not displayed on web.

**Web.config file:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rule 1R" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$"  />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}"  />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And my website url is : http://www.magazzinopneumatici.it/

Comment: Your link http://www.magazzinopneumatici.it/ , not work..